# Warning on "omz reload"

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Freshly installed oh-my-zsh.

When I run `omz reload`, I get:

```
_omz::reload:7: failed to write history file /Users/my_username/.zsh_history: permission denied
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What are the permissions of this file?